# ScrollWidth return ClientWidth instead the currect value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I'm building a slider with React and framer motion. My idea is to subtract scrollWidth with offsetWidth to get the remaining width of the element.
I always get the value of zero (somehow they are equal). I printed the object and I saw that scrollWidth value returns clientWidth instead.

In the object the value of scrollWidth is totaly different and I cant tell why.
[image: ScreenShot of the object]

Answer (score 0):

I am Creating This Same Project Carousel Slider In Next.js
But I got scrollWidth is Undefined
I dont Know What Happend But..
I got scrollWidth is undefined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6M4K.png)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import cardsUser from '../pages/CardsUsers'
const CardCaousel = () => {
    const [width,setWidth] = useState(0)
    const carousel = useRef()
    useEffect(()=>{
setWidth(carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth)
    },[])
  return (

    <div className="container max-w-full bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 p-5 bggradient">
    <div className="liveactionscontainer mt-20">
    <h1 className='text-center text-white font-extralight text-6xl mt-2 mb-3'>Live Actions </h1>
    <p className='font-extralight text-gray-500 text-center'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, suscipit repellat 
    <br/> 

    inventore dolor quia quos molestias quae vitae? Eveniet nobis, laborum voluptas culpa libero similique.</p>

<div className="myflex flex justify-center" data-aos="fade-right">

 <motion.div className="carousel">
 <motion.div
    drag="X"
    dragConstraints={{right:0,left:-width}}
    className="inner-carousel"
    >
{cardsUser.map((e)=>{
       return (
           <motion.div className='item' key={e}>
        <div className="mycolumn mb-10">
        <div class="nft">
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src={e.Imgsrc} alt="NFT"  />
          <h2>{e.name}</h2>
          <p class='description'>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>0.031 ETH</p>
            </div>
            <div class="duration">
         
             <button>Place bid</button>
            
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class='creator'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
              <img src={e.profileImg} alt="Creator" />
            </div>
            <p><ins>Creation of</ins><span className='text-white'> NF</span> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
 
        </div>
        </motion.div>
    
     );})}
     </motion.div>
     </motion.div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
  )
}

export default CardCaousel
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have Already Solved this Myself  So That's Why I am Not Updating This Question